# ChoiceBox onShown\onHidden methods don't work JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

While answering question about `ChoiceBox` I've found an interesting problem (bug, probably?). In Java 1.8u60 the following four methods were added for the `ChoiceBox`: `setOnShown`, `setOnShowing`, `setOnHidden`, `setOnHiding`. But I cannot get them working!

```
public class ComboBoxSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 450, 250);

        final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "jacob.smith@example.com",
                "isabella.johnson@example.com"
        );

        comboBox.setOnShown(event -> {
            System.out.println("ComboBox onShown");
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });
        comboBox.setOnShowing(event -> {
            System.out.println("ComboBox setOnShowing");
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });

        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "New Document", "Open ")
        );

        choiceBox.setOnShown(event -> {
            System.out.println("ChoiceBox onShown");
            System.out.println(choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });

        choiceBox.setOnShowing(event -> {
            System.out.println("ChoiceBox onShowing");
            System.out.println(choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });

        choiceBox.setOnHidden(event -> {
            System.out.println("ChoiceBox setOnHidden");
            System.out.println(choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });

        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("ChoiceBox selectedIndexProperty");
        });

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        grid.add(new Label("ComboBox: "), 0, 0);
        grid.add(comboBox, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("ChoiceBox: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(choiceBox, 1, 1);

        Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

For the `ComboBox` both `setOnShown` and `setOnShowing` methods work just fine, but for the `ChoiceBox` console output is empty except for `selectedIndexProperty` listener.
Is this a known bug?'cos I couldn't find anything related. Or there is something wrong with the code?

I use the latest JDK v1.8.0_121.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) doesn't even list those methods for `ChoiceBox`, so I'm surprised it even compiles....

Comment: @sillyfly yeah, I've submitted a bug to Oracle team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it indeed seems to be a bug.

Inspecting the code of `ChoiceBox` leads to the following: `ChoiceBox` fires these events with the wrong event type.

When you set the handler the following code is executed:

```
private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<Event>> onShown = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<Event>>() {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
        setEventHandler(ON_SHOWN, get());
    }

    ....
};
```

where `ON_SHOWN` is defined as a static field of the `ChoiceBox`:

```
public static final EventType<Event> ON_SHOWN =
        new EventType<Event>(Event.ANY, "CHOICE_BOX_ON_SHOWN");
```

However, when the event is fired ...

```
Event.fireEvent(this, value ? new Event(ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN) :
            new Event(ComboBoxBase.ON_HIDDEN));
```

... it uses `ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN` event type.

It seems to be a copy-paste-forgot to update issue.

In short: they are not working, because when you set the handlers, they expecting the wrong event type.

---

As a workaround until it gets fixed you can listen to the fired event types defined in `ComboBoxBase`.

With an `EventFilter`:

```
choiceBox.addEventFilter(ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN, e ->
    System.out.println("ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN was fired"));
```

Or with an `EventHandler`:

```
choiceBox.addEventHandler(ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN, e->
    System.out.println("ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN was fired"));
```

---

JDK bug ticket: [JDK-8175963 : ChoiceBox using events from ComboBox](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175963)

Comment: Great solution! Of course it looks a bit strange to use `ComboBoxBase` eventtypes for `ChoiceBox') Anyway, I've submitted a bug to Oracle team.

Comment: Updated the answer with the link to the JDK ticket.